# UnityEngine.UI não funciona

Tags: c#, unity3d

Então, estou aprendendo programação e no curso o professor colocou um codigo no algoritmo que é o "using UnityEngine.UI" para conseguir colocar os comandos e talz, só que quando fui fazer no meu unity, não pega, ele não reconhece como um comando
e sem isso não consigo fazer oque o professor pede.
(sou totalmente iniciante ok se for algo mt basico me desculpem.)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparece algum erro quando vc roda o programa?

Comment: Você instalou o SDK do uinity?

Comment: não aparece nenhum erro, oq só acontece é que o script não considera o UnityEngine.UI como um comando

Comment: como ver se eu instalei o sdk?

Comment: @JoãoFrancisco, você acaba de responder que não...

Comment: @JoãoFrancisco ao invés de colocar uma imagem com o código coloque o próprio código.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, João, na verdade não é um problema de compilação ou algo parecido, a sua IDE não está identificando a biblioteca do Unity, basta apagar os seguintes arquivos da pasta do seu projeto:

.vscode (no meu caso, que uso o VS Code),
Assimbly-CSharp.csproj,
NomeDoProjet.sln (A solução do Visual Studio, caso esteja usando)

Após isso, abra novamente algum script do seu projeto com a sua IDE e ele será carregado novamente sem nenhum erro.